# Ionic 3 - ios build --release requires a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, deployment, release

I've been trying left and right to get a succesful build for ios. Once I accidentally managed to get one build succesful but I'm unable to get another one.

No matter what I try I keep getting the error `error: exportArchive: "MyAppName.app" requires a provisioning profile.`.

- I've set up my profile, certs etc.
- From XCode I've changed the managed signing to my provisioning profile for both release and debug.
- Deployment info is set to iPhone only
- I've tried to do a `ionic cordova platform rm ios` and `ionic cordova platform add ios`. Then opened the poject in Xcode again and set the provisioning profiles.
- I've also tried to add more entries (team id, provisioning profile etc) to the `exportOptions.plist`, but they didn't last but it didn't really matter I guess because once I had a succesful build.

What am I doing wrong? What am I overlooking or maybe hasn't been documented to work today?

Comment: yeah documentation around this is really bad;/ outdated and often not precise. which one you used to perform what you do?

Comment: I've been able to solve the issues by updating my OSX and XCode versions to the latest versions.